# How do I define the index within the array?

Tags: php, symfony, google-books

I am trying to consume the Google Books API, but it says undefined index for "title", as I am attempting to search for a book title and for the results to appear within twig.

My Controller :-

```
public function googlebooksAction($id)
    {
        $client = new Client();
        $response = $client->get('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=id='.$id);
        $data = $response->json();
        $books = $data['title'];
        return $this->render('ReviewerReviewBundle:Google:googlebooks.html.twig',
            array(
               'title' => $books
            ));
    }
```

My Twig File :-

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}

{% block title %}{{ book.volumeInfo.title }}{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<h1>Google Books</h1>
    {% for book in books %}
        <article>{{ book.volumeInfo['title'] }}</article>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: The returned object doesn't have a title key. You should pass the items decoded response to your template like `'books' => $data['items']` and it should work the way you want it to. Also you can use `{{ book.volumeInfo.title }}`.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I have done what you have suggested which has gotten rid of the error however it is now coming up with this error - Key "volumeInfo" for array with keys "0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9" does not exist in ReviewerReviewBundle:Google:googlebooks.html.twig at line 3 ? Any Ideas

Comment: I assume you have, infact, named your variable `book` otherwise it should error out saying that `book` is undefined. The issue you are running into is because you are trying to access `book.volumeInfo.title` in your title block when book is just an array of books. If you removed that it would work, alternatively you could use `{{ books.0 is defined ? books.0.volumeInfo.title : 'Unknown Title' }}` to get the first title in your list if there are any.

Comment: thank you very much everything worked :) great advice